# Creating WebSocket server In Java

Tags: java, websocket

I need to create simple WebSocket client that sends bath and forth Json messages.

I have created service that makes handshake:

```
public class WebSocket {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3703);
            try {
                System.out.println("Server has started on 127.0.0.1:3703.\r\nWaiting for a connection...");
                Socket client = server.accept();
                System.out.println("A client connected.");

                InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
                Scanner s = new Scanner(in, "UTF-8");

                try {
                    String data = s.useDelimiter("\\r\\n\\r\\n").next();
                    System.out.println(data);
                    Matcher get = Pattern.compile("GET").matcher(data);

                    if (get.find()) {
                        System.out.println("found");
                        Matcher match = Pattern.compile("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").matcher(data);
                        match.find();
                        byte[] response = ("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
                                + "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                                + "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
                                + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: "
                                + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest((match.group(1) + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11").getBytes("UTF-8")))
                                + "\r\n\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8");
                        out.write(response, 0, response.length);


//Code for reading and decoding messages



                    }
                } finally {
                    s.close();
                }
            } finally {
                server.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

But what is the best way to realize message decoding? Is there any libraries I can use for this purposes?

What is the best approach to create `WebSocket` service in general? Should I use application server or I can create standalone service. What libraries I should use in case of standalone service?

Comment: [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-websocket-server-api.html) and [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/web-socket-howto.html) both have well known and solid WebSocket frameworks.

Comment: I would like not use application server if it is possible